# Discord Bot who disconnected a user from voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make my bot to send a message when someone is disconnected. That contains the one who got disconnected and the one who disconnected them.

But when I run the bot and disconnect someone nothing is happening.

Here is my code:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function (oldMember, newMember) {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel

  if (newUserChannel === null) {

    // User leaves a voice channel

    const fetchedLogs = await (oldMember, newMember).guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT',
    });

    const disconnectLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    const { executor } = disconnectLog;

    client.channels.cache.get("828731501016252417").send(`<@${executor.id}> Disconnected <@${oldMember.id}>`)
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason nothing is happening is because the `client.voiceStateUpdate` event now emits `oldState` and `newState` representing the `VoiceState`s of the member instead of the member itself. It's [changed in discord.js v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#client). As the [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) doesn't have a `voiceChannel` property, your `newUserChannel` will be `undefined`.

Your if statement (`if (newUserChannel === null)`) will always be false, as `undefined` is not strictly equal to `null`, so nothing inside it will get executed.

You could check if `newVoiceState.channel` is null instead. You should also check if the bot has the required `VIEW_AUDIT_LOG` permission before you try to fetch the logs. You also missed the `async` keyword in front of your callback function, you can only use `await` inside async functions.

Check the code below, it should work as expected.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
  // User leaves a voice channel
  if (newVoiceState.channel === null) {
    // check if the bot can view audit logs
    if (!oldVoiceState.guild.me.hasPermission('VIEW_AUDIT_LOG'))
      return console.log('Missing permission: "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG"');

    const fetchedLogs = await oldVoiceState.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
      limit: 1,
      type: 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT',
    });

    const { executor } = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    client.channels.cache
      .get('828731501016252417')
      .send(`${executor} disconnected ${oldVoiceState.member}.`);
  }
});
```

**PS:** The current function sends the last entry every time someone leaves a voice channel, even if they left on their own will. I think, `MEMBER_DISCONNECT` will only be logged when someone else kicked the member from the channel. You need to verify somehow if the last log entry is the same as the current voiceStateUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

[`voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event has [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) type parameters, not members.

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", function (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) {
  let newUserChannel = newVoiceState.channel

  if (newUserChannel === null) {

    // User leaves a voice channel

    const fetchedLogs = await (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState).guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT',
    });

    const disconnectLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    const { executor } = disconnectLog.executor;

    client.channels.cache.get("828731501016252417").send(`<@${executor.id}> Disconnected <@${oldVoiceState.id}>`)
}
});
```

Comment: I get                                                                                                                                  `const fetchedLogs = await (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState).guild.fetchAuditLogs({
                                  ^

ReferenceError: await is not defined `                                                                                              When I try to Disconnect somone

Comment: I tried to add `async` instead of `function` but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`